# Script ends even if there are still more commands after

Tags: command, applescript

I'm not sure what i am doing wrong but after this command finishes, the script ends yet there is still  another command to complete, would anyone know what I am doing wrong. Thanks

I enter this in, it runs through

```
tell application "Finder"
                activate
                display dialog "Are you sure you want to shut down your computer now?" buttons {"Restart", "Sleep", "Shutdown"} with icon alias ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:power.icns")
                if the button returned of the result is "Restart" then
                    set theSeconds to 10
                    repeat theSeconds times
                        display dialog theSeconds buttons {"Stop"} giving up after 1 with title "Restarting..." with icon 0 default button 1
                        set theSeconds to (theSeconds - 1)
                        set volume 6
                        beep 1
                    end repeat

                    tell application "Finder"
                        restart
                    end tell

                else
                    if the button returned of the result is "Sleep" then
                        set theSeconds to 10
                        repeat theSeconds times
                            display dialog theSeconds buttons {"Stop"} giving up after 1 with title "Sleeping..." with icon 0 default button 1
                            set theSeconds to (theSeconds - 1)
                            set volume 6
                            beep 1
                        end repeat

                        tell application "Finder"
                            sleep
                        end tell

                    else
                        if the button returned of the result is "Shutdown" then
                            set theSeconds to 10
                            repeat theSeconds times
                                display dialog theSeconds buttons {"Stop"} giving up after 1 with title "Shutting Down..." with icon 0 default button 1
                                set theSeconds to (theSeconds - 1)
                                set volume 6
                                beep 1
                            end repeat

                            tell application "Finder"
                                shut down

                                            end tell
```

and this is the command that comes after, but doesn't run

```
                            set appLocation to path to me as string
                            set theFile to appLocation & "Contents:Resources:iPanic.app"
                            tell application "Finder" to open file theFile

                            delay 8
                            tell application "Terminal"
                                activate
                                set currentTab to do script {"defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool YES"}
                                delay 1
                                do script {"Killall Finder"} in currentTab
                            end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the end of your script doesn’t run is that by the time the script gets to that point, your computer has either restarted, is sleeping, or has been shutdown.

The restart, sleep, or shutdown command needs to be the very last command in your script.

You can make the final part of your script into a subroutine, and call that subroutine before the restart, sleep, or shutdown commands.

Wrap the final part of your script like this:

```
on finalPart()
…
end finalPart
```

And then you call that subroutine like this:

```
finalPart() of me
restart
```

You can name the subroutine something more descriptive to you than “finalPart” of course.

Also, where you are calling the restart, sleep, and shutdown commands, you don’t need the tell block that is around them because you are already talking to Finder at that point. You can remove the line directly above and directly below the restart, sleep, and shutdown commands.

And here:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script {"defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool YES"}
    delay 1
    do script {"Killall Finder"} in currentTab
end tell
```

You don’t have to run a shell script with the Terminal app. The “do shell script” command is a Standard Addition that works in every app. And to quit Finder, all you have to do is tell it to quit. So unless you have more going on in your “Killall Finder” script than just quitting the Finder, you can probably write the above like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool YES"
    delay 1
    quit
end tell
```

Of course, if that part of the script is already within a Finder tell block, you can remove the tell command from the above.

Comment: thanks for informing me on all this :) i'm still learning applescript and my script is a bit messy but this helps. I'm just wondering for the 

`finalpart () of me
restart`

do i need to do that code for every button (sleep, restart, shutdown) then. So for the sleep command, i'll put the subroutine in then end in `finalpart() of me, sleep` and i have to copy and paste the subroutine for each command